# Indice invertido. Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, indices

estoy tratando de crear un índice invertido a partir de:

```
{'doc01': {'A': 1,'B': 3,'C': 5},
 'doc02': {'A': 1,'B': 3},
 'doc03': {'B': 5,}}
```

Mi objetivo es el siguiente:

```
{'A': [('doc01', 1),('doc02', 1)]
     'B': [('doc01', 3),('doc02', 3),('doc03', 3)]
     'C': [('doc01,5')]
```

Lo he intenta así pero el resultado no es el deseado tal y como muestro:

```
di1 = {'doc01': {'A': 1,'B': 3,'C': 5},
 'doc02': {'A': 1,'B': 3},
 'doc03': {'B': 5,}}

index = defaultdict(dict)
for key, val in di1.items():
  for subkey, subval in val.items():
    index[subkey][key] = subval

{'A': {'doc01': 1,'doc02': 1,'doc03': 1}
 'B': {'doc01': 3,'doc02': 3,'doc03': 3}
 'C': {'doc01'}}
```

Comment: El ejemplo del resultado deseado está mal. La clave A no aparece en doc2, y el valor de la clave B en doc3 es 5 y no 3 como has puesto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los elementos de tu índice tienen que ser listas, por lo que debes usar el tipo `list` para del `defaultdict()`.

A cada una de esas listas le irás añadiendo (con `.append()`) las parejas clave-valor correspondientes:

```
index = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in di1.items():
  for subkey, subval in val.items():
    index[subkey].append((key, subval))
```

Resultado:

```
{'A': [('doc01', 1), ('doc02', 1)],
 'B': [('doc01', 3), ('doc02', 3), ('doc03', 5)],
 'C': [('doc01', 5)]}
```